# groovy null safe operator not working

Tags: groovy

Trying to do this:

```
var = obj?.Prop ?: obj.Prop.toLowerCase()
```

But I keep getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'Prop' on null object
```

Isn't this what `?` is for? My understanding is obj?.Prop is the same as:

```
if ( obj != null && obj.Prop ) { .. }
```

Sometimes obj is null, but if its not I want to set obj.Prop to lower case- cant set toLowerCase() on a null object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do `obj?.Prop?.toLowerCase()`

The [Elvis operato](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator)r (`?:`) is causing `obj.Prop.toLowerCase()` to be evaluated when the `obj?.Prop` is null. It's equivalent to writing

```
var = (obj?.Prop != null) ? obj.Prop : obj.Prop.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression following the ?: Is the alternative for the case where the preceding expression is null. If you use the same object in your alternative as you used in the preceding part  then you will trigger an npe

Instead do

```
obj?.Prop?.toLowerCase()
```